# Real time processing of high speed video session

Tags: android, opencv, opengl-es, android-camera2

I'm looking for a way to process video images (**without recording**) at 120fps - on Android.

Going over all relevant SO questions, I couldn't find an answer to my question.

The docs says one must use CameraConstrainedHighSpeedCaptureSession to work with high speed video sessions.
For regular capture session I am using an ImageReader and process the images in C++.
But for high speed sessions I can't use it.

Is there a way to solve this issue using Camera2 API?
If not, is there a c++/opengl way to do it?

Important - my goal is to NOT record the video.
I've looked at Grafika & bigflake but they use the old Camera API.

Any help is much appreciated.
Thank you.